# Software RAID vs Hardware RAID

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid

I need more info about RAID.  I have a 1U server from Dell R210 with an onboard RAID controller, which I am not able to get to work with Ubuntu install, so I setup a software RAID on Ubuntu.

My question is now, what can I do? Right now I am testing the server with software RAID, but I don't know if this is the best solution.  Can somebody help me?

Comment: Post (relevant section) of the output of lspci -v

Comment: I almost want to close this for sheer lack of trying to spell correctly.

Comment: spell-checking is built into most browsers these days, so please take some time to actually write a coherent question.  Do you really expect a useful answer when your question is barely readable?

Comment: Anyway, a simple search of software vs hardware raid (http://serverfault.com/search?q=software+vs+hardware+raid) returns many useful results that provide answers to similar questions.  http://serverfault.com/questions/214/raid-software-vs-hardware http://serverfault.com/questions/133212/onboard-raid-vs-software-raid http://serverfault.com/questions/57884/software-vs-hardware-raid1-mirror

Comment: Oh, and you could have provided some useful technical information.  For example, which of the 7 possible storage controllers do you have have in your [Dell R210](http://www.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/poweredge-r210/pd.aspx?refid=poweredge-r210&cs=555&s=biz)?

Answer (score 2):

Wayne is right, if you're using Linux, kernel's soft RAID work's like charm.
You have to keep in mind that if hardware RAID is broken, you need to rebuild the RAID with the same hardware vendor.
Take a look on this document, i think it's what you need.
[Hardware RAID vs. Software RAID: Which
Implementation is Best for my Application?](http://www.adaptec.com/nr/rdonlyres/14b2fd84-f7a0-4ac5-a07a-214123ea3dd6/0/4423_sw_hwraid_10.pdf)